# Javascript counting number of objects in object

Tags: javascript, object, count

I have an object something like:

```
Object {0=Object, 1=Object, 2=Object} // Output from console.log(obj.Data);
```

But there is no way that I can count the number of objects in object, then finally get the attribute value from the sub objects.

I have tried

```
console.log(obj.Data[0].length); // It does not work

console.log(obj.Data.length); // It does not work
```

This is a bit tricky for me. Hope you guys can help.

Comment: could you please post complete object?

Comment: Why are you using an object this way? There's a lot of things to consider to your question - you need to understand what properties are, which ones are enumerable, how prototypes can add to the mess here, and so on. Why not just use an array?

Comment: Even though this q is marked a duplicate, the accepted answer here works easier for me that the solutions given in the first asked question.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, with excellent performance and compatibility with both old and new browsers, is to include either [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) in your page.

Then you can use either `_.size(object)` or `_.keys(object).length`

For your `obj.Data`, you could test this with:

```
console.log( _.size(obj.Data) );
```

or:

```
console.log( _.keys(obj.Data).length );
```

Lo-Dash and Underscore are both excellent libraries; you would find either one very useful in your code. (They are rather similar to each other; Lo-Dash is a newer version with some advantanges.)

Alternatively, you could include this function in your code, which simply loops through the object's properties and counts them:

```
function ObjectLength( object ) {
    var length = 0;
    for( var key in object ) {
        if( object.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    return length;
};
```

You can test this with:

```
console.log( ObjectLength(obj.Data) );
```

That code is not as fast as it could be in modern browsers, though. For a version that's much faster in modern browsers and still works in old ones, you can use:

```
function ObjectLength_Modern( object ) {
    return Object.keys(object).length;
}

function ObjectLength_Legacy( object ) {
    var length = 0;
    for( var key in object ) {
        if( object.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
            ++length;
        }
    }
    return length;
}

var ObjectLength =
    Object.keys ? ObjectLength_Modern : ObjectLength_Legacy;
```

and as before, test it with:

```
console.log( ObjectLength(obj.Data) );
```

This code uses `Object.keys(object).length` in modern browsers and falls back to counting in a loop for old browsers.

But if you're going to all this work, I would recommend using Lo-Dash or Underscore instead and get all the benefits those libraries offer.

I set up a [jsPerf that compares the speed of these various approaches](http://jsperf.com/counting-object-properties). Please run it in any browsers you have handy to add to the tests.

Thanks to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) for [suggesting `Object.keys` for newer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16976940/1202830) in his answer.

Comment: Using the conditional operator to do this kind of feature-detection seems overly complicated.

Comment: Hi, can you explain on this? Can I put this into a function and call whenever we need it?

For safe precaution to users who use older browser, I will try to adopt this.

Comment: It's a pretty common way to do it, but fair enough, you could easily do the same thing with an if statement. The main thing is to do it outside the function instead of inside the function.

Comment: @BryanLearn - This *is* a function. Leave out the `console.log()` calls and the end and you can use it as is. The `console.log()` calls illustrate how to call it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, its abit complicated but I guess I will study on this.

Comment: I tried Object.keys(obj.Data) and it return 0,1,2 how can I get the total count or does it return in this format?

Comment: Bryan, call `ObjectLength(obj.Data)`

Comment: I guess I have figured out. Thanks!

Comment: @BryanLearn - also check my updated answer. I think the simpler code at the top of the answer is the best way to go. It should certainly be easier to understand, and that's always a good thing.

Comment: @BryanLearn - Another update! :-) Please check out my latest suggestion, which is to use either of the excellent libraries Lo-Dash or Underscore. I think you would find these very useful. If for any reason you can't use one of these, do note that I was wrong about the simple code being fastest - if you do include your own code from my answer, the best version of `ObjectLength()` is the one at the end of the latest update (include both the two separate functions and the `var ObjectLength = ...` after them).

Comment: @PaulPhillips - thanks for the comment on the conditional operator. You were right! I updated the code so it should be easier to follow. It still uses the conditional operator, but in a much simpler way instead of all that nested stuff.

Comment: Thank you @michaelGeary, you are awesome! I am using Underscore. It is so easy to use.

Comment: the latter would be better, for var obj1 = { 'test1': 123, 'test2': 456, length: 6 },  _.size(obj1) gives you 6 while _.keys(obj1).length gives you 3 (more accurate).

Comment: You can also do ```values(object).length```

Answer (score 116):

In recent browsers you can use:

```
Object.keys(obj.Data).length
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

For older browsers, use the `for-in` loop in Michael Geary's answer.

Comment: Hi Barmar, somehow it does not log under console... Can you help me by explaining?

Comment: `keys` is not a property of the object to be counted. @BryanLearn: He meant `Object.keys(obj.Data).length`. Should be closed as a dupe anyway :-)

Comment: To me this is the answer. Adding a library like lodash is not part of a solution. Also you can't rely on a `for in` loop to output in an expected order.

Comment: Much better answer.

Comment: @BenRacicot If you only care about the length, why does the order matter?

Comment: Looks like this works back to Internet Explorer 9 for anyone wondering, so unless you need to support really old browsers it should be fine

Comment: @KellyBarber The answer is 8 years old. `Object.keys()` was relatively new, and IE8 wasn't as prehistoric.

Comment: This really should be the answer.

Answer (score 42):

> Try [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MymHb/1/)

```
var list ={}; var count= Object.keys(list).length;
```

Comment: You rather should upvote other answers instead of re-posting the solutions :-)

Comment: when i started making demo , no one had given this answer.

Comment: @Bergi . You should look at timestamp before comments. Sometimes a better answer exists, but no one cares.

Comment: @FendiSetiawan Looking at the timestamps, these are 7 year old comments on a closed question? (And even then, indeed Barmar's answer was posted, and edited, much earlier than this)