# Issue in accessing object property in javascript shows undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am just calling api which returns josn encoded data and trying to print object property but shows undefined but when I print that object , the object has that property and value.

**my code**

```
function sendData(postData, url){
        var response = apiCall(postData,url);
        console.log(response.email)
        console.log(response.count);
    }


    function apiCall(postData, postUrl){
        var response = {};
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : postUrl,
            data    : postData, 
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
         }).success(function(data) {  
                console.log(data)
                for (var attr in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(attr)) response[attr] = data[attr];
                }  
           });

         return response;   
    }
```

**php based api**

```
<?php 
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $response = array();

    $response['email'] = $_POST['oauth']['email'];
    $response['type'] = $_POST['oauth']['type'];
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

**response data in console**

> Object {email: "sameerdighe14@gmail.com", type: "google"}

Comment: Please add your response data.

Comment: Do you really need this line `if (data.hasOwnProperty(attr))`  when you are already doing `(var attr in data)`?

Comment: @brk it checks for property and if there is property with empty field then it will not assign it to other object.

Comment: I added a response data @lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use promises to make it work. Your `success` function is called async once the HTTP-Request has finished with success. In that way `return response;` is executed before the request has been finished -> so it is still an empty object `{}`. Use [AngularJS promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to make it work. This is a simple working [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5fg0ft6o/).

```
function sendData(postData, url){

    var filteredData = {};

    apiCall(postData,url).then(function (response) {

        for (var attr in response.data) {
            if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
                filteredData[attr] = response.data[attr];
            }
        }

        console.log(filteredData.email);
        console.log(filteredData.count);
    });
}


function apiCall(postData, postUrl){
    return $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : postUrl,
        data    : postData,
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
}
```

Comment: I still have a same problem . prints undefined in console

Comment: Ohh worked for me .

Comment: but still count is not working @lin

Comment: @SaMeEr Count what?

Comment: console.log(filteredData.count);  this statement.

Comment: `obj.count` is not a property. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976904/javascript-counting-number-of-objects-in-object

Comment: but still when I am returning filterData from where sendData got called so there i am accessing same obj.email property which printing undefined.

Comment: @SaMeEr Right, same issue as before. Please check how promises work and make youself understood how async behaviors work.

Comment: @SaMeEr this example may will make it more clear http://jsfiddle.net/f4zq026g/ =)

Comment: ok. Thank you @lin

Answer (score -1):

The code is not running in the order which you expect. `$http` takes time to run, and therefore `apiCall` is returning response before it's been modified.

To fix this, you need to use a promise to ensure that your code runs only when you have all of the data which you need.

Additionally, the data returned from `$http` has a property `data` which contains the result from the call.

```
function sendData(postData, url) {
  // subscribe to promise, and add your code in the then block
  apiCall(postData,url)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.email);
      console.log(response.count);
    });
}

function apiCall(postData, postUrl) {
  // return the promise
  return $http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : postUrl,
    data    : postData, 
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).success(function(response) { 
    var result = {};
    for (var attr in response.data) {
      if (response.data.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        result[attr] = response.data[attr];
      }
    }  
    return result;   
  });
}
```

---

Note that the `data` property from a $http request is guaranteed to be a plain object without extra properties on its prototype, so you don't really need the `hasOwnProperty` check. apiCall can be simplified:

```
function apiCall(postData, postUrl) {
  // return the promise
  return $http({
    method  : 'POST',
    url     : postUrl,
    data    : postData, 
    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).success(function(response) { 
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Comment: This will not work. `.then(function(response)` holds the raw callback data of `$http` and not the data returned by the success part.

Comment: `success` returns a promise. Therefore any modification are kept. Source: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3a3db690a16e888aa7371e3b02e2954b9ec2d558/src/ng/http.js#L910

Comment: True, but this promise is for handling the success promise itself. Please check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/3a3db690a16e888aa7371e3b02e2954b9ec2d558/src/ng/http.js#L415 & http://jsfiddle.net/5uancso0/

Comment: Please bring some feedback, this discussion is also interesting to me